# How can I retrieve the alias for a DataFrame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.0.2.  I have a DataFrame that has an alias on it, and I'd like to be able to retrieve that.  A simplified example of why I'd want that is below.

```
def check(ds: DataFrame) = {
   assert(ds.count > 0, s"${df.getAlias} has zero rows!")    
}
```

The above code of course fails because DataFrame has no *getAlias* function.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like this but I wouldn't go so far to claim it is supported:

- Spark < 2.1:

  ```scala
  import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.SubqueryAlias
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

  def getAlias(ds: Dataset[_]) = ds.queryExecution.analyzed match {
    case SubqueryAlias(alias, _) => Some(alias)
    case _ => None
  }
  ```
- Spark 2.1+:

  ```scala
  def getAlias(ds: Dataset[_]) = ds.queryExecution.analyzed match {
    case SubqueryAlias(alias, _, _) => Some(alias)
    case _ => None
  }
  ```

Example usage:

```scala
val plain = Seq((1, "foo")).toDF
getAlias(plain)
```

```
Option[String] = None
```

```scala
val aliased = plain.alias("a dataset")
getAlias(aliased)
```

```
Option[String] = Some(a dataset)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I can use that for now and hopefully it this capability gets added in a later API release.

Comment: In spark 2.0.2, SubqueryAlias only had 2 parameters, so I had to modify it to 
    case SubqueryAlias(alias, _) => Some(alias)

Comment: In Java it's may be done by using **instanceof** operator `ds.queryExecution().analyzed() instanceof SubqueryAlias`.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: as stated above, this code relies on undocumented APIs subject to change. It works as of Spark 2.3.

After much digging into mostly undocumented Spark methods, here is the full code to pull the list of fields, along with the table alias for a dataframe in PySpark:

```
def schema_from_plan(df):
    plan = df._jdf.queryExecution().analyzed()
    all_fields = _schema_from_plan(plan)

    iterator = plan.output().iterator()
    output_fields = {}
    while iterator.hasNext():
        field = iterator.next()
        queryfield = all_fields.get(field.exprId().id(),{})
        if not queryfield=={}:
            tablealias = queryfield["tablealias"]
        else:
            tablealias = ""
        output_fields[field.exprId().id()] = {
            "tablealias": tablealias,
            "dataType": field.dataType().typeName(),
            "name": field.name()
        }
    return list(output_fields.values())

def _schema_from_plan(root,tablealias=None,fields={}):
    iterator = root.children().iterator()
    while iterator.hasNext():
        node = iterator.next()
        nodeClass = node.getClass().getSimpleName()
        if (nodeClass=="SubqueryAlias"):
            # get the alias and process the subnodes with this alias
            _schema_from_plan(node,node.alias(),fields)
        else:
            if tablealias:
                # add all the fields, along with the unique IDs, and a new tablealias field            
                iterator = node.output().iterator()
                while iterator.hasNext():
                    field = iterator.next()
                    fields[field.exprId().id()] = {
                        "tablealias": tablealias,
                        "dataType": field.dataType().typeName(),
                        "name": field.name()
                    }
            _schema_from_plan(node,tablealias,fields)
    return fields

# example: fields = schema_from_plan(df)
```

Comment: Nice, I've resulted to just doing this for now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65968414/naming-a-cached-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

**For Java**:

As @veinhorn mentioned, it is also possible to get the alias in *Java*. Here is a utility method example:

```
public static <T> Optional<String> getAlias(Dataset<T> dataset){
    final LogicalPlan analyzed = dataset.queryExecution().analyzed();
    if(analyzed instanceof SubqueryAlias) {
        SubqueryAlias subqueryAlias = (SubqueryAlias) analyzed;
        return Optional.of(subqueryAlias.alias());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```