# How to extract alias from a pyspark dataframe.

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We know that `df.columns` provides the column names, `df.dtypes` provides the column names and their respective types. However, I could not find a similar attribute which provides us with the assigned aliases of a dataframe. Even `df.schema.jsonValue()` does not contain this information.

Where, if any, is this information stored, and how does one access it?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by _assigned aliases of a dataframe_?

Comment: [How can I retrieve the alias for a DataFrame in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41249806/8371915)

Comment: @philantrovert, Suppose we write `df = df.alias('foo')` and at some later stage we would like to find all aliases of `df` using `alias_list = df.get_aliases()`, then `alias_list = =['foo']`. Currently no such function `get_aliases()` exists.

Comment: @user8371915, thanks, the link provided attempts to provide a solution, but the solution not a documented feature and is probably subject to change. Also, it is for spark, not pyspark.