# Extending Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I want to extend the `Dataset` class from Apache Spark by adding some properties to it. Let's assume we want to have `NamedDataset`. The only difference being that an instance of `NamedDataset` has a `string` field which defines the name of that particular dataset. The following is my attempted solution that does not compile:

```
class NamedDataset2[A : Encoder](prev: Dataset[A], name: String) extends Dataset[A](prev.sparkSession, prev.queryExecution, implicitly[Encoder[A]]) {

}
```

The compiler cannot resolve the constructor. I have provided the necessary parameters to the constructor though.

What is the recommended way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: As you can see in the source code ([**_here_**](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L171)), the constructor of the class is `private` to the `sql` package, that is why the compiler can not find it. IMHO, I do not think is a good idea to extend such class _(not sure why it is not final)_. Rather, why do not you create a wrapper class which contains the `Dataset` and the name instead?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Or use [`aliases`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41249806/6910411) for that matter.